# Updating MutableLiveData<ArrayList<User>>

Tags: android, kotlin, mutablelivedata

Until now I have been changing User in `MutableLiveData<ArrayList<User>>` by deleting and adding User(with updated attributes)

Is there any other option to update a User in `ArrayList` of `MutableLiveData<ArrayList<User>>?`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update a user in the `ArrayList` within a `MutableLiveData`, you don't necessarily need to delete and re-add the user. You can follow these steps:

> Assuming you have a MutableLiveData<ArrayList> named `userListLiveData`

**Step 1:** Retrieve the current list

```swift
val currentList = userListLiveData.value ?: arrayListOf()
```

**Step 2:** Find the user to update

```swift
val userToUpdate = currentList.find { it.id == userId }
```

> Replace `userId` with the ID of the user you want to update.

**Step 3:** Update the attributes of the user

```swift
userToUpdate?.apply {
    // Update user attributes here
    name = "New Name"
    // Update other attributes as needed...
}
```

**Step 4:** Update the MutableLiveData with the modified list

```swift
userListLiveData.value = currentList
```